# Typescript can't access exported method from another module

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

Not able to reference and use exported methods from another module. Getting an error stating 'There is no exported member in SecondModule'.

```
module FirstModule{
    export class someClass{
         constructor(method: SecondModule.exMethod)   //Getting Error here: 'There is no exported member in SecondModule'
         {}
    }
}

module SecondModule{
    export function exMethod(){
        return function(input){
             //do something
             return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a function reference as a type; however, you can restrict the constructor to a specific function type that allows functions with a signature like `exMethod`.

Here's an example:

```
module FirstModule {
    export class someClass {
         constructor(method: () => (input) => any) {
         }
    }
}

module SecondModule {
    export function exMethod() {
        return function(input) {
             // do something
             return result;
        }
    }
}

new FirstModule.someClass(SecondModule.exMethod); // ok
new FirstModule.someClass(() => {});              // error
```

If you want to force `SecondModule.exMethod` to be passed in you might as well skip that and call the function directly in `someClass`:

```
module FirstModule {
    export class someClass {
         constructor() {
             SecondModule.exMethod()(5); // example of calling it
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I call the function as SecondModule.exMethod(input) directly in the FirstModule without going through the constructor?

Comment: @shyamalparikh so you want these two statements to be equivalent? `SecondModule.exMethod()(4);` and `SecondModule.exMethod(4);`

Comment: Sorry, what if I directly call SecondModule.exMethod()(4) from the FirstModule? Will there be any initialization issues?

Comment: @shyamalparikh i just updated the answer to be something that doesn't mix `FirstModule` and `SecondModule` together and keeps them separate. You could call `SecondModule.exMethod()(4)` just fine from the first module if you wanted though.

Comment: In the updated code how will the FirstModule identity 'exMethod' just by the parameters and return type? What would happen if SecondModule has methods with similar return type and parameters?

Comment: @shyamalparikh any functions with a similar return type and parameters then those could be passed in as well. If you want to force `SecondModule.exMethod` to be passed in, then you might as well skip passing it in and call it directly in `someClass`. I've updated the answer with that.